# How to add fix height and width in pixels of div in tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working with `react` and `tailwind css`. I want to give `100px` `height` and `width` to my `div`. If anyone have an idea how to do it in `tailwind css` please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `div` tag you need to add classes for `height` and `width`. In `tailwind-css` we can give `fix` `height` and `width` using `[]` (square brackets). Like,
`<div className="h-[100px] w-[100-px]">Your Content</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use **h-[number]** or h-px to set an element to a fixed height.
Use **w-[number]** or w-px to set an element to a fixed width.

Comment: we need to use square brackets not curly brackets. Like, `h-[....]` `w-[....]`